# python 3.11.0 Ошибка при установке библиотеки Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Текст ошибки представлен ниже. Ошибка происходит при использовании команды "pip install aiogram". Установил отдельно библиотеки wheel и pyproject, но ошибка осталась. PIP обновен до последней версии.

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to 
install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Или ждите, пока опубликуют бинарники yarl/frozenlist/multidict для 3.11, или используйте 3.10

Answer (score 0):

Скачай Visual Studio и в установке поставь галочки на пакеты "Node.js, Классические приложения .Net и С++, так как Microsoft запретило скачивать, юзай VPN.
После чего перезапусти ПК и пробуй качать.